# MySQL no actuaiza Vista de una Tabla

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, select, vistas

Tengo el siguiente problema, en mi Base de Datos MySQL tengo una tabla llamada calificaciones, inserto datos desde una página PHP a dicha tabla y todo ese proceso pasa sin ningún problema, el problema se presenta cuando desde PHPMyAdmin hago una consulta sobre la tabla, si hago una consulta abierta por ejemplo:

```sql
SELECT * FROM calificaciones;
```

Me muestra todos los registros incluyendo los nuevos, pero cuando hago una consulta como la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT `id`, 
`indicador`, 
`mes`, 
`periodo`, 
`tipo`, 
`resultado`, 
`semaforo`, 
`calificacion`, 
`ponderacion`, 
`nombre`, 
`payroll`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(`evaluado` SEPARATOR ', ') AS evaluado_concat, 
ROUND(AVG(`semaforo`),0) AS n_sema,
SUM(`calificacion`) AS n_cali, 
SUM(`ponderacion`) AS n_ponde 
FROM `calificaciones` 
GROUP BY `payroll`, `codigo`;
```

No muestra los nuevos registros creados, me aparecen solo los registros que cargue previamente mediante un .sql, pero los registros insertados desde la página PHP no los muestra.

Y lo mismo hace con una Vista que cree de la tabla calificaciones, no se actualiza, solo muestra lo que inserte desde el .sql.

```
Versión del servidor: 10.4.6-MariaDB / Versión de PHP: 7.3.9
```

Alguien tiene alguna idea de este problema, al alguien más le ha sucedido?.

Gracias por sus comentarios.

Saludos.

Comment: Recuerda la vista unicamente va a mostar los datos del `SELECT` de como fue creada, por lo tanto si ingresas nuevos datos dependiendo de este pueda que muestre como no. Con respecto al `INSERT` puedes asegurarnos que si se estan ingresando los datos?

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia de edición @DavElsanto. En efecto puedo asegurar que se insertan los datos, la consulta que se usa para la creación de la vista es la misma que comparti, por otro lado si creo un nuevo registro directo a la tabla (PHPMyAdmin) este registro si se muestra en la vista, pero creo un registro desde la página PHP y en la tabla se muestra el nuevo registro pero en la vista no.

Comment: Sigo haciendo pruebas, y por ejemplo si hago un INSERT directo a la base de datos con la opción de INSERT (PHPMyAdmin) de la tabla, se muestra el registro tanto en la tabla como en la vista, pero si hago un INSERT directo desde una página PHP, en la tabla se inserta pero no se muestra el registro en la vista, no sé que sea o porque tiene ese comportamiento.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que tu consulta está agrupando por dos columnas: `GROUP BY payroll, codigo;` significa que si los nuevos registros insertados asumieron valores ya existentes en otros registros aparecerán agrupados, como ya ocurría. Puedes probar a insertar un `payroll` y un `codigo` **totalmente nuevos** y verificar si esa nueva fila aparece o no.

Comment: @A. Cedano Gracias por el comentario, en efecto analizando la consulta identifico que el campo mes impactaba en la vista por lo que agregue el campo para ser agrupado y con ello quedo solucionado. Gracias por sus comentarios. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema radicaba en la consulta de la vista ya que el campo -mes- no estaba agrupado y por ello no mostraba los registros, este campo tenía valores como Enero 2020, Febrero 2020, etc. entonces al hacer la consulta y no agruparlo generaba que los registros no se mostraran de forma correcta, una vez que agrupe el campo me reflejo los registros que iba insertando desde la página PHP.

¡Gracias por su comentarios!

Saludos.

Comment: Te aconsejaría que no guardes datos como `Enero 2020, Febrero 2020`, etc. Más bien guarda un campo `DATETIME` el cual será menos propenso a errores y más flexible a cualquier evolución de la BD.

Comment: Lo tomaré en cuenta, Gracias por el Tip @A. Cedano